# Comment Views returned by Google Data API for youtube does not match

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Google Data API v3 to fetch some statistical data about a channel.

https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=CHANNEL_ID&part=statistics&key=SERVER_API_KEY

The commentCount that is obtained in the response does not match with that shown on the Youtube Channel discussion page.

What may be the reason for this difference.

Comment: Maybe that api is not fetching you the data from the production database.